# How to read xml file with multiple sub nodes in java with SAX parser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax, saxparser

how can i read an xml file which has nodes and then again subnodes and this sub nodes can further have sub nodes

**like XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<school>
    <student id="1">
        <firstname name="ankush">
            <test>sample </test>  //......here can be more sub nodes

        </firstname>
        <lastname>thakur</lastname>
        <email>beingjavaguy.gmail.com</email>
        <phone>7678767656</phone>
    </student>

</school>
```

Code i have used to read this:

```
public class ReadXml extends DefaultHandler{

public void getXml(){
        try {

            SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();

            DefaultHandler defaultHandler = new DefaultHandler(){

                String firstNameTag="close";
                String lastNameTag="close";
                String emailTag="close";
                String phoneTag="close";
                String testTag="close";

                public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("FIRSTNAME")) {
                        firstNameTag = "open";
                    }
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("TEST")) {
                        testTag = "open";
                    }

                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("LASTNAME")) {
                        lastNameTag = "open";
                    }
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("EMAIL")) {
                        emailTag = "open";
                    }
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("PHONE")) {
                        phoneTag = "open";
                    }
                }


                public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
                        throws SAXException {

                    if (firstNameTag.equals("open")) {
                        System.out.println("First Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                    }
                    if (testTag.equals("open")) {
                        System.out.println("Test Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                    }

                    if (lastNameTag.equals("open")) {
                        System.out.println("Last Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                    }
                    if (emailTag.equals("open")) {
                        System.out.println("Email : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                    }
                    if (phoneTag.equals("open")) {
                        System.out.println("Phone : " + new String(ch, start, length));
                    }
                }


                public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
                        throws SAXException {

                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("firstName")) {
                        firstNameTag = "close";
                    }
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("test")) {
                        testTag = "close";
                    }

                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("lastName")) {
                        lastNameTag = "close";
                    }
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("email")) {
                        emailTag = "close";
                    }
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("phone")) {
                        phoneTag = "close";
                    }
                }
            };

            saxParser.parse("xmlToRead/student.xml", defaultHandler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but the **OUTPUT**

```
First Name : 

First Name : sample 
Test Name : sample 
First Name : 


Last Name : thakur
Email : beingjavaguy.gmail.com
Phone : 7678767656
```

Any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: Quick google search fixes everything :) http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/

Comment: this only contaion single nodes

Comment: Use dom parser to convert xml as Document object..

Comment: i dont want to use dom parser ...its just an example i will have lagre xml files for around 1 gb

Comment: the only way is to use a parser

Answer (score 0):

As a kind of middle way, it is possible to use DOM4J to process sub trees and then detach them, thereby minimizing memory consumption:

```
    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();

    reader.addHandler("/school/student", new ElementHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onStart(ElementPath elementPath) {
            // nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onEnd(ElementPath elementPath) {
            Element student = elementPath.getCurrent();
            /*
             * process the current student, then detach it from the tree
             */
            student.detach();
        }
    });

    reader.read(...));
```

Here, the document will only contain one <student> element at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for us to teach you how to write SAX applications. There are books and tutorials on the subject: read them. Be aware that it isn't easy. Elliotte Rusty Harold's book on XML and Java is excellent.